# Increment a number on page load in a windows form. in c# for Visual studios 2015

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, auto-increment

This is what i currently have but it only changed the label to 1 and when i close the page but not the application and then re load the page it is still at 1.
Any help here would be amazing, thanks.

```
    //Form 1
    public partial class BasketScreen : Form
    {
        private void PurchaseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // show the purchase products screen.
            this.Hide();
            PurchaseScreen ps = new PurchaseScreen();
            ps.Show();
        }  
    }



    //UniqueNumber is the number i wish to display.
    //OrderNumber is the name of the label where i want to display the UniqueNumber

    //form 2
    public partial class PurchaseScreen : Form
    {
        //private int UniqueNumber = 0;  This was the issue

        //This line was the fix.
        private static int UniqueNumber = 0;
    }

    private void PurchaseScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UniqueNumber++;
        OrderNumber.Text = UniqueNumber.ToString("000");
    }

    private void BackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        BasketScreen bs = new BasketScreen();
        bs.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Where are these unique numbers ultimately stored? The reason I ask is because you can manage this within the application, but then the next time the application starts you'll be back at 1 again.

Comment: I'm hoping that the numbers are only stored while the application is running, and then when the application is closed the are reset to 0.    the application is like a basket app but when the purchase button is pressed it generated an order number each time. essesntially just keeping count of how many times that page has loaded during the applications run time.     but i cant figure out why it stays at one :(

Comment: Ive added the back button in the code snippet to show how i am closing the purchase screen. then i am re-loading the screen using the button in form 1

Comment: Make your `UniqueNumber` variable `static`.  If it is not static then it will be reset to zero each time you create a new instance of the `PurchaseScreen`

Comment: Brian Rogers You absolute Legend :D haha knew it would be something simple i was missing.